# How can I use selenium to get the last element in a list?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have such a structure

[image]

How does it look visually

[image]

I'm trying to get the last item and click on it, but the 4th item is selected.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id=\"page-body\"]/div/div[2]/ul[last()]"))).click();
```

How do I click on the last item and on 55?

Comment: Why don't you put some attributes on those elements to make them easier to target?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do not understand what you're talking about(

Comment: Well you're trying to click on a link to page 55, how much easier would that be with e.g. `[data-qa="page-link"][data-qa-value="55"]`? That way you don't have to build a complicated XPath that could easily go out of date as things move around.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What if tomorrow number will be 256?

Comment: You can put other attributes on too, if you want something to tell you it's the last one that's fine. E.g. `[data-qa-rel="last"]`. The point is to rely on useful information not just structure.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I'll try. But I'm afraid it will not help. [data-qa-rel="last"] Will the last element be selected at this moment?

Comment: If by *"at this moment"* you mean in the DOM you've shown in the question, no; you need to *add* those attributes, so they're set on the appropriate elements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay. Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look up elements using xpath like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id=\"page- body\"]/div/div[2]/ul[last()]"))).click();
```

you basically look up the last `ul` element that is

1. the only one in your snippet.
2. the container for `li` elements that you should actually look for.

So, your code could look like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']/ul/li[last()]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"//div[@class="pagination"]/li[not(contains(@class, 'arrow') and last()])]/a"
```

Breaking down:

Inside a div with class pagination -> `//div[@class="pagination"]`

Look for the li without the arrow class -> `li[not(contains(@class, 'arrow')`

And fetch the last one -> `and last()]`

Inside this li, look for a link -> `/a`